# How Can I set State in stateless Function, in a nested Function?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-functional-component

I know that I can't change the state in a stateless function when the function is nested, though I am only this far away to set the state in order for the page work as I would want. I want to keep this as a functional component. The issue is below I want to set the language under this function, or any other way works I know how to do this with Class component, though unless there will be 10 votes to do that would prefer to stay with functional.

```
  function changeTounge(e) {
  console.log("Write something!!");
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.value);
  //setLanguage({ iso2: "lv", speak: "Latviešu" });
}
```

the full code is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function PrimaryNav() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState({ iso2: "us", speak: "English" });
  return (
    <div className="primary-nav">
      <ul className="navigation">
        <li className="active">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="has-child">
          <a href="#nav-homepages">Opportunities</a>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="nav-homepages" className="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                {OpsOption("RealEstate", "Real Estate")}
                {OpsOption("Vehicles", "Vehicles")}
                {OpsOption("JobSearch", "Job Search")}
                {OpsOption("PersonalCompany", "Personal Company")}
                {OpsOption("Inves`enter code here`tInIdea", "Invest In Idea")}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact">Help &amp; Support</Link>
        </li>

        <li className="has-child language">
          {ActiveLanguage(language.iso2, language.speak)}
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="nav-languages" className="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                {LanguageOption("English", "us")}
                {LanguageOption("British", "gb")}
                {LanguageOption("Latviešu", "lv")}
                {LanguageOption("Estonia", "ee")}
                {LanguageOption("Lithuania", "lt")}
                {LanguageOption("Russian", "ru")}
                {LanguageOption("Deutch", "de")}
                {LanguageOption("French", "fr")}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function LanguageOption(label, classLabel) {
  return (
    <li
      onClick={changeTounge.bind(this)}
      data-id={label}
      data-value={classLabel}
    >
      <Link to="#nav-locations">
        <span className={"flag-icon flag-icon-" + classLabel}></span>
        {"  "}
        {label}
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
}

function changeTounge(e) {
  console.log("Write something!!");
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.value);
  //setLanguage({ iso2: "lv", speak: "Latviešu" });
}

function OpsOption(pageLink, label) {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={"/" + pageLink}>{label}</Link>
    </li>
  );
}

function ActiveLanguage(iso2, activeLanguage) {
  return (
    <a href="#nav-languages">
      <span className={"flag-icon flag-icon-" + iso2}></span> {activeLanguage}
    </a>
  );
}

export default PrimaryNav;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nesting the components inside of the main component, they'll be able to access and set its state. This is still a functional pattern here.

The other option would be to add a prop to your children components, and pass in the setLanguage function through that prop.

Also, you don't need the `changeTounge.bind.this` in functional react :D. In general, if you're using `this` at all in functional react... that's a red flag.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PrimaryNav = () => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState({ iso2: "us", speak: "English" });
  
  const changeTounge = (e) => {
    console.log("Write something!!");
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.value);
    setLanguage({ iso2: "lv", speak: "Latviešu" });
  }

  const OpsOption = (pageLink, label) => {
    return (
      <li>
        <Link to={"/" + pageLink}>{label}</Link>
      </li>
    );
  }

  const ActiveLanguage = (iso2, activeLanguage) => {
    return (
      <a href="#nav-languages">
        <span className={"flag-icon flag-icon-" + iso2}></span> {activeLanguage}
      </a>
    );
  }

  const LanguageOption = (label, classLabel) => {
    return (
      <li
        onClick={changeTounge}
        data-id={label}
        data-value={classLabel}
      >
        <Link to="#nav-locations">
          <span className={"flag-icon flag-icon-" + classLabel}></span>
          {"  "}
          {label}
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="primary-nav">
      <ul className="navigation">
        <li className="active">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="has-child">
          <a href="#nav-homepages">Opportunities</a>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="nav-homepages" className="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                {OpsOption("RealEstate", "Real Estate")}
                {OpsOption("Vehicles", "Vehicles")}
                {OpsOption("JobSearch", "Job Search")}
                {OpsOption("PersonalCompany", "Personal Company")}
                {OpsOption("Inves`enter code here`tInIdea", "Invest In Idea")}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact">Help &amp; Support</Link>
        </li>

        <li className="has-child language">
          {ActiveLanguage(language.iso2, language.speak)}
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="nav-languages" className="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                {LanguageOption("English", "us")}
                {LanguageOption("British", "gb")}
                {LanguageOption("Latviešu", "lv")}
                {LanguageOption("Estonia", "ee")}
                {LanguageOption("Lithuania", "lt")}
                {LanguageOption("Russian", "ru")}
                {LanguageOption("Deutch", "de")}
                {LanguageOption("French", "fr")}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}





export default PrimaryNav;
```

Comment: Goush this was so simple. Yeah, need to get more practice! This is what I was looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably tidier ways to do some of this, but this seems to work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function PrimaryNav() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState({ iso2: "us", speak: "English" });
  return (
    <div className="primary-nav">
      <ul className="navigation">
        <li className="active">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="has-child">
          <a href="#nav-homepages">Opportunities</a>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="nav-homepages" className="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                {OpsOption("RealEstate", "Real Estate")}
                {OpsOption("Vehicles", "Vehicles")}
                {OpsOption("JobSearch", "Job Search")}
                {OpsOption("PersonalCompany", "Personal Company")}
                {OpsOption("Inves`enter code here`tInIdea", "Invest In Idea")}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact">Help &amp; Support</Link>
        </li>

        <li className="has-child language">
          {ActiveLanguage(language.iso2, language.speak)}
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div id="nav-languages" className="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                {LanguageOption("English", "us", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("British", "gb", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("Latviešu", "lv", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("Estonia", "ee", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("Lithuania", "lt", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("Russian", "ru", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("Deutch", "de", setLanguage)}
                {LanguageOption("French", "fr", setLanguage)}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function LanguageOption(label, classLabel, setLanguage) {
  return (
    <li
      onClick={(event) => changeTounge(event, setLanguage, label, classLabel)}
      data-id={label}
      data-value={classLabel}
    >
      <Link to="#nav-locations">
        <span className={"flag-icon flag-icon-" + classLabel}></span>
        {"  "}
        {label}
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
}

function changeTounge(e, setLanguage, label, classLabel) {
  console.log("Write something!!");
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.value);
  setLanguage({ iso2: classLabel, speak: label });
}

function OpsOption(pageLink, label) {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={"/" + pageLink}>{label}</Link>
    </li>
  );
}

function ActiveLanguage(iso2, activeLanguage) {
  return (
    <a href="#nav-languages">
      <span className={"flag-icon flag-icon-" + iso2}></span> {activeLanguage}
    </a>
  );
}

export default PrimaryNav;
```